# Удаление строк из html таблицы с помоью javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Впервые столкнулся с `js`, и передо мной стоит задача: имеется таблица, в которой один столбец - форма с текстовыми полями, нужно по нажатию кнопки удалить все строки таблицы, в которых поля формы не заполнены.

```js
function deleteRows() {
  var flag = true;
  while (flag) {
    flag = false;
    if (document.getElementById('count').value == "") {
      ell = checkboxElement.closest("tr");
      ell.parentElement.removeChild(ell);
      flag = true;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Название</th>
            <th scope="col">Фото</th>
            <th scope="col">Описание</th>
            <th scope="col">Количество</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">Планшеты</th>
            <td><img src="img/inv/planshet.jpg" width="320" height="180"></td>
            <td>Планшеты можно взять на складе</td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="count" placeholder="Всего 6"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">Подушка</th>
            <td><img src="img/inv/podushka.jpg" width="320" height="180"></td>
            <td>Подушку можно взять на складе</td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="count" placeholder="Всего 2"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <button onclick="deleteRows()" class="btn btn-dark">Далее</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Вопросы: как исправить код, потому что он нерабочий, и нормальный ли это вариант решения, или же можно реализовать такой механизм как-то иначе?

Comment: Я б каждой строке присваивал свой id и потом удалял по нему.

Comment: `Id` - это у каждого элемента должен быть уникальный у элемента не может быть двух `id` и не может быть у двух или более элементов одно и тоже  `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id должны быть уникальными для страницы, воспользуйтесь классом:

```js
function deleteRows() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.count').forEach(item => {
    if (item.value == "") item.closest("tr").remove()
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- <form> -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Название</th>
          <th scope="col">Фото</th>
          <th scope="col">Описание</th>
          <th scope="col">Количество</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Планшеты</th>
          <td><img src="img/inv/planshet.jpg" width="20" height="10"></td>
          <td>Планшеты можно взять на складе</td>
          <td><input class="form-control count" type="text" placeholder="Всего 6"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Подушка</th>
          <td><img src="img/inv/podushka.jpg" width="20" height="10"></td>
          <td>Подушку можно взять на складе</td>
          <td><input class="form-control count" type="text" placeholder="Всего 2"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button onclick="deleteRows()" class="btn btn-dark">Далее</button>
  <!-- </form> -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`type="button"` - для наглядности, что бы форма не закрывалась, удали ее

```js
var count = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
    if (count[i].value === '') {
      count[i].parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Название</th>
            <th scope="col">Фото</th>
            <th scope="col">Описание</th>
            <th scope="col">Количество</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">Планшеты</th>
            <td><img src="img/inv/planshet.jpg" width="320" height="180"></td>
            <td>Планшеты можно взять на складе</td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="count" placeholder="Всего 6"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">Подушка</th>
            <td><img src="img/inv/podushka.jpg" width="320" height="180"></td>
            <td>Подушку можно взять на складе</td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="count" placeholder="Всего 2"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <button id="btn" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Далее</button>
  </form>
</div>
```